# Parse link through Javascript instead of Inline

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, popup, modal-dialog

I have a number of social media site links which i would like to parse through a popup box. Here is an example of one of those links:

```
<li>
    <a class="sprite_reddit" href="http://www.reddit.com/submit" onclick="window.open('http://www.reddit.com/submit?v=5&amp;noui&amp;jump=close&amp;url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&amp;title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title), 'reddit','toolbar=no,width=840,height=750'); return false;"></a>
</li>
```

Rather than include window.open in the html I would like this link to parse through the following javascript which centers the popup box in the screen.

```
function MyPopUpWin(url, width, height) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    //Allow for borders.
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    //Allow for title and status bars.
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    //Open the window.
    window.open(url, "Window2", "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
}
```

What do I need to change in order to achieve this or is it not possible with this kind of link?

Thanks heaps.

Comment: My advice, avoid `window.open` _always_; bad usability. Use a modal dialog with an iframe if necessary.

Comment: @elclanrs I disagree, some social sharing links such as google+ works much better when opening a new window.

Comment: @David: Ad-blocker will prevent it from opening I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The open function is supported in every major browser version but not every browser supports all the parameters you have set. Some like screenX and Y are no longer supported I guess.
Checkout this link for more information:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp